# How do I write console output values (from eclipse) in excel sheet through selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, manual-testing

I want to print my verification messages in Excel instead of Eclipse console.
Can you provide your suggestion to do above scenario in Selenium?

Ex: Getting the Page title and printing in the console:

```
String title1=driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(title1);
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file

Comment: Voting for closing because this question is related to Software Development, not testing.